# Web Authentication (like firebase auth) that supports a11y and i18n

Tags: facebook, authentication, internationalization, accessibility

I am building a web app using the MEAN stack and I want to enable user sign-in with Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc. The caveat is that I also want to support accessibility and internationalization.

The Auth solutions that I've looked at usually popup a new window - which is not ideal for my app; I want the login to be part of the normal page flow.

I can write my own UI markup that does the authentication on the server side using JWT and exposed APIs (like Facebook API) but I was hoping that there is already a solution like Firebase Auth that meets my needs. Any suggestions?

Comment: So what would happen if the user has to login to Facebook? They would fill in the username and password in your app that you then send to Facebook? That is not allowed by Facebook Terms of Service or Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: Good point @WizKid. I guess a custom solution using JWT would require registration prior to the ability to sign in. I really want to leverage the social networking logins so that users don't have another username/pwd to remember. But I must have a11y and i18n.  There surely must be a solution out there somewhere.